# How to read and write extremely large data from device

Tags: java, architecture, tcp, hadoop, memcached

I am building a location tracking system for one of our client. They have GPS devicees installed in vehicles and each device has programmed with a server IP and a port number, We have developed a TCP listener who listen the request sent by device. These devices sent a request every minute.

Actual problem is that, There are 1,00,000 lakh GPS device sent a request every minute, so storing information is very difficult , I am not able to figure out the best approach to store data coming from devices, Should i store in File or in memcached?

Please help me to find the best way to handle this problem. Please remember that each GPs device is GPRS enabled and due to that  they have internet connectivity so they can talk to our backend server.
Sometimes these devices can not find internet since vehicle will be moving across all places, but once device gets internet connection, it sends all packet at one time, which is suppose to send every minute.

So i am finding the best way to handle this problem, I am using Java programing language.

Thanks in Advance !!!!

Comment: Just as a word of advice - using "lakh" as a unit in an international forum isn't a great idea; it's not widely used. It's also not clear whether you meant to write "1,000,000 lakh" or "100,000" lakh - putting a comma before *two* 0s is unusual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option that comes to mind is [Apache Flume](https://blogs.apache.org/flume/entry/flume_ng_architecture) as a way to collect data into Hadoop.
Another (commercial) option is [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to handle this amount of data, I'd set up a bunch of message queue servers to queue all incoming data, and a set of listeners to take messages from these queues and interprete them. ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ and HornetQ all can theoretically handle thousands of messages per second.

HornetQ, for example, has a [high performance journal](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html/persistence.html) that will very efficiently balance between an in-memory journal and paging to the file system. On Linux, it got a [native integration with LibAIO](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html/libaio.html) to optimize file system interaction.

If you set up a hardware load balancer, you can configure the GPS devices to communicate with the load balancer, and these will forward to one of the message queue servers.

The bottleneck might be then to get the data from the message queue listeners to your database. To avoid this you might use [MySQL Cluster's horizontal partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Cluster#Horizontal_data_partitioning).

Comment: Thanks geryfairer, could you please help suggest message queue server in java, and please let me know that each gps device communicate on same server and on same port,so how could i handle million request at the same time,so time out must not happens? Please suggest me where could i store all incoming data either in memoey or file system? should i use memcached?

Comment: I know HornetQ will keep as much messages in memory, and page to disk when necessary.

Comment: A Hardware Load Balancer such as Cisco Catalyst can take all incoming data on one IP number and port, and redistribute it to hundreds of servers. I know HornetQ will keep as much messages in memory as it can, and page to disk when necessary. But this is only for temporary storage. What do you want to do with the data next?

Comment: As GPS devices frequntly communicating with server, we recieve data packet in server side, each data packet contains information like latitude and longitude, but for extracting these information we need to parse incoming data , as data packet comes in different format. So i am finding a way - where listener class read the data packet - write in some temporary storage - then writes in MYSQL Database, since we an not do these all activities together, since millions GPS devices communicating to same server. So please suggest me the write way to handle millions request and storage and parsing?

Comment: See updated answer. If you just need a sort of buffer for your incoming data, a message queue is imho the right tool for the job. What's the protocol that your GPS devices will use, or can you decide that? If you can, go for STOMP: it's supported by more and more MQ Servers.

Comment: Hey greyfairer, I wanted to use other protocol like http or RPC, but we can not program into GPS device, they send the data in very specific format, data packet start with # and ends with ~. As we can not program into GPS device, how can we use RPC or HTTP protocol, since we must create the behaviour or XML into client side. Can you suggest me how to use other protocol other than TCP, we are using TCP protocol by simplly creating TCP listener.As you suggested, i am looking into HornetQ and setting a message queue server to get data from GPS device, then will write a program to read packet.

Comment: Hmm, you will apparently need to write a TCP listener indeed, and that listener can put the binary message into hornetq. You could start that TCP listener, the hornetq server and the hornetq listener(s) in a single standalone java process if you want.